# Exclude first 2 posts with meta_key from loop

Tags: loop, query-posts

I have 2 loops on a page. The first displaying 2 featured posts:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured_post',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
query_posts($args);
?>
```

The second display all posts:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="meta">DO STUFF</div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

How can I exclude the first 2 "featured_post" items from the second loop?

Comment: Write the postID of the first two posts to an array and then add a `post__not_in` argument to the second query:  `post__not_in => $my_array`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: That kind of makes sense. How can I write the first two IDs into an array? Thanks

Comment: Do an initial query with a limit of 2 and then add those IDs to your next query.

Answer (score 1):

First point is that you should NOT use `query_posts()` for custom queries.  The better approach is to use the `WP_Query` class.   More info in the [WP docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

This example will display your 2 featured posts and then exclude them in the second query.

```
// We will push the ID of your featured posts to this array
$excl_posts[] = '';

// Query arguments from your featured posts query
$feat_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured_post',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

// Instantiate new WP_Query instead of using query_posts()
$featured = new WP_Query( $feat_args );

if ( $featured->have_posts() ):
  while ( $featured->have_posts() ):
    $featured->the_post();

    // Do stuff with each posts
    echo get_the_title() . "<br>";

    // Push current postID onto the exclude array
    $excl_posts[] = get_the_ID();
  endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

$excl_feat_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'post__not_in' => $excl_posts,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured_post',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$excl_featured = new WP_Query( $excl_feat_args );

if ( $excl_featured->have_posts() ):
  while ( $excl_featured->have_posts() ):
    $excl_featured->the_post();
    echo get_the_title() . "<br>";
  endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```